# Build FQCN from a string

Tags: php, oop

Sorry if this is a dup. Is there a native PHP function like `::class` but for string variables or constants? I.e. from a string build the FQCN using the active namespace and `use` alias. E.g.:

```
namespace test;
use foo\bar;

echo fqcn_from_a_string("zip"); // should print 'test\zip'
echo fqcn_from_a_string("bar"); // should print 'foo\bar'
echo fqcn_from_a_string("\yap"); // should print 'yap'
```